# SignalR Objective-C connection frequently fails with unacceptable content-type: text/event-stream

Tags: ios, asp.net, signalr

I am using the `SignalR` `Objective-C` library at https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC to connect my `iOS` app to my `SignalR` backend running on `Azure`. I just make a regular connection and open a hub proxy normally:

```
conn = [SRHubConnection connectionWithURLString:endpoint queryString:@{ ... }];
[conn start];
hub = [conn createHubProxy:@"main"];
```

I've put a handler on connect and error events of my hub connection. My hub initially connects, but it immediately disconnects with `request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/event-stream`.

I've tried different transports, but no avail. For example, if I force web socket transport, then I'm getting `HTTP` `503` or `400` errors. But this is what is get when I don't specify a specific transport. My `SignalR` app is hosted inside `ASP.NET` and I can also reproduce the issue locally without `Azure`.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: @StaffordWilliams nope regular stable 2.2

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I'm facing similar issue. Did you find any solution to this.

Comment: @Gaurang it somehow went away but honestly I don't remember what I did. I recommend a clean install of the ObjC library, and try specifying a transport (e.g. webSockets) explicitly instead of auto. See if it helps. Also, try different connections (e.g. my home Wifi was different and a public Wifi was different and my iPhone cellular hotspot was different in terms of stability for different connection types) to your SignalR server. Also make sure your path doesn't contain an extra `/signalr` or `/mainhub` or anything like that. I've tried all and one of them apparently worked but don't remember